Laravel 11 Artisan : Call to a member function handleCommand() error
The updated Laravel 11 is causing significant issues for me. There are no kernel.php files, and some service provider files are missing as well. I have to manually add the kernel, and every time I make adjustments in my bootstrap/app.php file, the artisan file throws an error. I can't even run the php artisan command without encountering an error. Here is the code in my app.php file inside the bootstrap directory.
$app = Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function ($middleware) {
        $middleware->add(\App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserType::class);
        $middleware->add(\App\Http\Middleware\StudentMiddleware::class);
        $middleware->add(\App\Http\Middleware\TeacherMiddleware::class);
        $middleware->add(\App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class);



    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })
    ->create();

$app->register(AppServiceProvider::class);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);

This is the error:
`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function handleCommand() on int in C:\Classes\3rd year\2nd sem\CCS 106\Laravel\FINAL PROJECT\grand_line_university\artisan:13
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\Classes\3rd year\2nd sem\CCS 106\Laravel\FINAL PROJECT\grand_line_university\artisan on line 13

n:13
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\Classes\3rd year\2nd sem\CCS 106\Laravel\FINAL PROJECT\grand_line_university\artisan on line 13
PS C:\Classes\3rd year\2nd sem\CCS 106\Laravel\FINAL PROJECT\grand_line_university> php artisan serve
line 19

Fatal error: Cannot use "::class" on value of type string in C:\Classes\3rd year\2nd sem\CCS 106\Laravel\FINAL PROJECT\grand_line_university\bootstrap\app.php on line 
19
PS C:\Classes\3rd year\2nd sem\CCS 106\Laravel\FINAL PROJECT\grand_line_university> php artisan
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function handleCommand() on int in C:\Classes\3rd year\2nd sem\CCS 106\Laravel\FINAL PROJECT\grand_line_university\artisan:13
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\Classes\3rd year\2nd sem\CCS 106\Laravel\FINAL PROJECT\grand_line_university\artisan on line 13

n:13
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\Classes\3rd year\2nd sem\CCS 106\Laravel\FINAL PROJECT\grand_line_university\artisan on line 13
PS C:\Classes\3rd year\2nd sem\CCS 106\Laravel\FINAL PROJECT\grand_line_university> php artisan
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function handleCommand() on int in C:\Classes\3rd year\2nd sem\CCS 106\Laravel\FINAL PROJECT\grand_line_university\artisan:13
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\Classes\3rd year\2nd sem\CCS 106\Laravel\FINAL PROJECT\grand_line_university\artisan on line 13

I am new at laravel, this is really hard.
I tried to manually add the kernel and have to adjust the bootstrap->app.php. But when I modified it especially the middleware part, the artisan file got modified also maybe because even tho I undo the changes, the artisan command still wont run because it says it had error in line 13 artisan file.

I just found out what's the problem, I forgot to return the $app.
Please make sure to include the return $app at the end of the code if you store it in an $app variable. This will ensure that the configured Laravel application is returned and used correctly.
$app = Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function ($middleware) {
        Route::middleware([CheckUserType::class, StudentMiddleware::class, TeacherMiddleware::class, AdminMiddleware::class]);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })
    ->create();

$app->register(AppServiceProvider::class);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);

return $app;

